# Python selenium waiting to download file completely

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I am writing code to download an Android APK file. It worked. However, I  faced trouble in the process of waiting for the file to download completely. I want to download many files, and each file has a different size, so I can't set the `time.sleep(time)` in general.

I try to combine a `Thread` and a `While loop`, and it worked. But, in the cut-off internet case, my code is still in the infinite while loop because at that time, the file is not downloaded completed and it is like that `.crdownload`.
Please help me with the issue.

```
def waitingDownload():
   path = "C:\\Users\\ASUS\\anaconda3\\phd_implement\\download_apk\\tmp\\*.apk"
   files = glob.glob(path)
   if(len(files)!=0):
       return True
   else:
       return False

#Setup web driver
chromedriver = 'C:\\Users\\ASUS\\anaconda3\\phd_implement\\chromedriver.exe'
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")
prefs = {'profile.default_content_setting_values.automatic_downloads': 1,"download.default_directory" : "C:\\Users\\ASUS\\anaconda3\\phd_implement\\download_apk\\tmp\\"}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
web = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
web.maximize_window()
# Download
url="https://download.apkcombo.com/com.avast.android.secure.browser/Avast%20Secure%20Browser_7.5.2_apkcombo.com.apk?ecp=Y29tLmF2YXN0LmFuZHJvaWQuc2VjdXJlLmJyb3dzZXIvNy41LjIvNDYzMC5jZWZhYTAzZTYwOTY3NGY0Y2Y2YWRiMTk1N2VkMzhlODMzYTExNGQzLmFwaw==&iat=1681553964&sig=4cc693ff4b5dfe4adea4030b65b8e454&size=198815248&from=cf&version=latest&lang=en&fp=1dce2e74bf37995f5efd03cd5877afb5&ip=130.25.102.251"
def task(url):
   web.get(url)
# create a thread
thread= Thread(target=task(url))
# run the thread
thread.start()
# wait for the thread to finish
print('Waiting for the download file...')
while True:
    if(waitingDownload()):
        break
thread.join()
print('Download completed')
web.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change your `waitingDownload()` method to take in the filename you are waiting for and a timeout and have it handle all the waiting.

```
def waitingDownload(filename, timeout_in_seconds):
    path = f"C:\\Users\\ASUS\\anaconda3\\phd_implement\\download_apk\\tmp\\{filename}"
    timeout = datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=timeout_in_seconds)
    while len(glob.glob(path)) == 0 and datetime.now() < timeout:
        time.sleep(1)
    # if you want to do something on failure, maybe assert or write to log that {filename} was not downloaded within {timeout_in_seconds}, etc.
```

then take it out of the loop, etc. Updated section of code below,

```
print('Waiting for the download file...')
while True:
    if(waitingDownload()):
        break
thread.join()
```

changes to

```
print('Waiting for the download file...')
waitingDownload("something.apk", 120))
thread.join()
```

Comment: I appreciate your help but in your code. You also put a timeout. As I mentioned, if you put timeout, it can't be applied for all the apk files because each apk file has a different size.

Comment: @nistelrooy41001662 Understood but I did that with your comment in mind. The code checks every second to see if the file is downloaded. What I've added is an outside limit that the script won't cross so that if the file never finishes downloading for some reason, the script will gracefully fail. If it finishes before the timeout, the script can continue. The method also allows you to add a different timeout for each file that you can tweak based on size so that you don't end up with a one size fits all solution.